# Why when I try to 'make' mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1 it gives me error?

Tags: c++, mysql, connector

I'm running Mountain Lion and I downloaded mysql-connector-c++-1.1.1.tar.gz. Boost and mysql is installed. 
These are the steps I follow:
1 'CMake . -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=/usr/local/boost_1_52_0' and it's ok
2 'make clear' and it's ok
3 'make' and when it arrives to 35% stops saying:

`[ 35%] Building CXX object examples/CMakeFiles/connect.dir/connect.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable connect
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file ../driver/libmysqlcppconn-static.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../driver/libmysqlcppconn-static.aignoring file CMakeFiles/connect.dir/connect.cpp.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): CMakeFiles/connect.dir/connect.cpp.o

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xce 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [examples/connect] Error 1
make[1]:**  [examples/CMakeFiles/connect.dir/all] Error 2
make: ** [all] Error 2`

What do I have to do?